# Fetch d3.js array from a url

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, d3.js, bottle

This is the kind of data that I have

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("kdahfa"), "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T00:11:00.000+0000"), "Time" : 660.0, "Name" : "Sam" }   
{ "_id" : ObjectId("aabhk"), "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T01:00:00.000+0000"), "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T02:14:25.000+0000"), "Time" : 4465.0, "Name" : "Bob" }  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("bak"), "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T19:00:00.000+0000"),     "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T19:52:22.000+0000"), "Time" : 3142.0, "Name" :     "Sam" }
```

I wrote a python(bottle) code to fetch the data from mongoDB server and run it on local host. The url is http://localhost:8080/result.

```
  @bottle.route('/result')
     def grab_record():
     bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
     a = dbcoll.find_one({},{'_id':False})
     a['minTime'] = str(a['minTime'])
     a['maxTime'] = str(a['maxTime'])
     response.content_type = 'application/json'  
     return dumps(a)
```

Now I wish to create a d3.js graph from this taking help from http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641. I want the task array in the example.js to take data from the url/mongodb. What changes should I make to my d3.js code to make it function according to my requirements?

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/result", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.maxTime = parseDate(d.maxTime);
    d.minTime = parseDate(d.minTime);
    d.Time = +d.Time;
});

var taskNames = ["Bob", "Sam"];

taskStatus = {
"Bob": "bar",
"Sam": "bar-failed",
};

var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus);
gantt(tasks);
});
```

These are the changes in the example.js file that I've made so far. I am getting an error
**Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function**
I wish to create an array of the returned d3.js objects and use it like it is used on http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641.

Comment: Check in browser whether `http://localhost:8080/result` returns json.

Comment: You are getting a document and you are trying to access a document in array like manner.Obviously its going to throw an error.

Comment: @SiddP {"minTime": "2016-04-02 00:00:00", "maxTime": "2016-04-02 00:11:00", "Time": 660.0, Name:"Bob"}. This what http://localhost:8080/result shows.

Comment: And as you can see in the python code above  response.content_type = 'application/json'  so I am assuming that it returns json. Please help me here!

Comment: I want to create an array of the json objects.

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma What should I do then?

Comment: Convert that data into which d3 will accept . 
`d3.json("http://localhost:8080/result", function(error, data) { convertData(data)}`
`function convertData(data){//convert Here}`

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma Can you please elaborate? I am still getting the error after using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = dbcoll.find_one({},{'_id':False})
```

In this line, you are only querying for one entry in your database, that is why the result returned is a single object instead of an array (probably you also need to change the first parameter `{}` to `[]` or something to denote array but I am not familiar with `dbcoll`.

You need to change `find_one` into `find` or something, and you will get an array.

Then the post-processing, you needs to iterate through the array of `a`:

```
a = a.map(function(b){
     b['minTime'] = str(b['minTime'])
     b['maxTime'] = str(b['maxTime'])
     return b;
}
```

In MongoDB there is a method `find`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: dbcoll is just a variable name for a collection in a mongodb database.

Comment: do you know how to take data from a url instead of a json/csv file in d3.js? I'll be glad for your help.

Comment: @glitterati updated the answer, `d3.json` is the way to load `json` file via `url`. I am afraid you are not understanding some basic concepts here. your `url` will return a `json` file.

Comment: I have used find instead of find_one earlier but that ends up giving time in miliseconds since epoch. Is there a way to convert that into the standard time that d3.js can render in the d3.js code I have mentioned? d.maxTime and d.minTime to be speecific. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641 This is the kind of output that I am looking for

Comment: @glitterati to convert from miliseconds to date object: `date = new Date(time); // convert a time in milliseconds to a Date object`

Comment: Changed my d3.js code to d3.json("http://localhost:8080/result", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.maxTime = new Date(d.maxTime);
  d.minTime = new Date(d.minTime);
        d.Time = +d.Time;
    });

var taskNames = ["Sam", "Bob"];

taskStatus = {
    "Sam": "bar",
    "Bob": "bar-failed",
};

var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus);
gantt(data);
});
Error is tasks is not defined in the file ganttchartd3v2.js

Comment: I'm so sorry. I am a beginner to d3.js. But I understand what the error means here. All I wanted to ask was to change the function to return the array of json objects(returned from the url) and store it in the tasks variable and how its done. So that I can proceed with the rest of the code like the example that I'd linked. Thanks a lot for whatever help you've provided though!

Comment: @glitterati the other way is to define a function that takes in the data as argument and render the chart, then call it inside callback.

Comment: I had tried that. That's when i got the error of tasks not defined even though I did not make use of the tasks variable anywhere in my program. I had replaced gantt(tasks) with gantt(data) as you can see in one of my comments.

Comment: @glitterati if you have confirmed that no occurrence of tasks is present, then it means your client code in the browser is not refreshed. Try disable cache

Comment: @glitterati btw if you look at chrome console, you can see the exact line number and content of line that used the variable tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113326/discussion-between-glitterati-and-paradite).